# "Npm Run SJS" Is Not Working

Tags: json, npm, npm-run

I've forked a project from GitHub, and I want to run the command `npm run sjs`, but it gives me an error. This is what it says:

```html
> vodafone@0.1.0 sjs C:\Users\audre\fantastic-website\vodafone\vodafone
> json-server ./data/phones.json -p 1234 --watch

'json-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vodafone@0.1.0 sjs: `json-server ./data/phones.json -p 1234 --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vodafone@0.1.0 sjs script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\audre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-07T09_35_19_168Z-debug.log
```

Please help; thanks a lot!

Comment: did you remember to run `npm install`?

Comment: I ran `npm i` a couple of times but it still didn't work.

Comment: can you please share details about the repo?

Comment: I forked it from a user on GitHub because I volunteered to help with the project. The link is https://github.com/catezee/vodafone.

Comment: I haven't done anything with the project yet, though. This is very recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR;

just run `npm install json-server` and you'll be OK.

## Explanation

### npm scripts

When running a script via *npm*, node is looking for the command in:

1. local `node_modules/.bin` folder (things that are in `package.json`)
2. global `node_modules/.bin` folder (things that you've installed with `npm install -g my-package`)
3. your standard shell `PATH`

### your problem

In that case, I guess that the creator of this repo had the `json-server` package installed, either locally without stating so in `package.json` or globally.

### recommendation

My recommendation is that you run `npm install --save json-server` and update the `package.json` file.
Actually, I did it already for you: https://github.com/catezee/vodafone/pull/1